# CIQRCodeGenerator produces wrong image

Tags: swift, qr-code, cifilter

There is a problem with QR code generation using the following simple code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let image = generateQRCode(from: "Hacking with Swift is the best iOS coding tutorial I've ever read!")
    imageView.image = image
}

func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5.3, y: 5.3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This code produces the following image:

[image]

But when magnifying any corner marker, we can see the difference in border thickness:

[image]

I. e. not every scale value produces correct final image. How to fix it out?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you show is expected whenever you use a non-integer scale, such as 5.3. If having consistent marker widths is something you care about, use only integer scales, such as 5 or 6.

Comment: I agree with You. But I want to be free to use non-integer scale in order to generate image of any size with millimeter accuracy.

Comment: In that case, the behavior you point out here is unavoidable whenever non-integer scales are involved.  You can try using a fancier interpolation (bilinear or bicubic interpolation), but although it may lead to more "even" thicknesses, it may have other problems in your situation; namely blurring.